# Carabiner Cache Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I posted on the Carabiner wiki but wanted to see if anyone here was able to get Carabiner for CI cache working, no matter what i try it will not write the cache to the folder, and I gave the folder 777 permissions. Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to run a chown on the folder?

from ssh

cd /path/to/directory
chown ./* user:group -R